# AIC or similar selection techniques for Variograms?

Tags: model-selection, aic, variogram, geostatistics

I have a very basic question: how does one choose the "best" variogram? It is possible to fit different models to an empirical variogram, e.g. `nugget`, `spherical`, `hole` etc.

However, how does one decide which one is the best? I see that sometimes R² is used for model selection, but don´t the different theoretical models hold different numbers of parameters? If so, R² would be biased and an IT-approach (AIC, BIC etc.) would be more suitable. I did not really understand if the models fitted to the empirical variogram have different numbers of parameters.

A nice overview on the models is given here:
[Theoretical Variogram Models](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/stat/chap34/sect12.htm)

Any thoughts are much appreciated! Suggestions on "how-to-in-R" most welcome! :)